# Pass different variable names for multiple includes

Tags: jsp, jspinclude

I am including a jsp file more than once on a single page. I have duplicate html on my page which is why I'm using jsp includes.

I have two input fields in the included file. Is there a way to pass different element id names for each included file?

So to summarise: 
 - Two jsp includes both requesting example.jsp
 - Two input fields in example.jsp
 - Find a way to pass two unique element id names for each include

Answer (score 0):

You can save different value/identifier/flag in `session` before including two different jsp files

Comment: The jsp included files are the same. I should also note that I am totally new to jsp and I'm simply using it as a way to avoid duplicated HTML so my knowledge is almost nothing so any example would be a huge help. At the moment I'm using <%@ include file="example.jsp" %> but obviously I'm not parsing a variable with this.

Comment: do this
<%@ include file="example.jsp?id=1" %> for 1st include
and<%@ include file="example.jsp?id=2" %> for 2nd include

Then, get this id like this
String id = request.getParameter( "id" );

Comment: The server reports a 500 not found when I add ?id=a at the end of the file name.

Comment: 500 error code is not due to your code/programming error

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: The above seems like a good way but due to the 500 problem is there another way to do this?

Comment: Clear the history and caches of browser, and clean and rebuild the project, and then run it, may b 500 error resolve.
There can be other way to do this, but it depends on your code, it will be helpful if you share your code

Comment: I did the above and no change. I cant post the back-end code because its not mine I'm simply handing the front-end side of things and have been using includes to avoid duplicate HTML. Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: you can save the attrbute id as 1 in session before the 1st include
<%@ include file="example.jsp" %>
and you can save the attribute id as 2 in session before the 2nd include
<%@ include file="example.jsp" %>

Comment: I instead decided to tackle the problem using javascript which solves the problem for me. Thanks for trying to help.